# MKMapSnapshotter return a black background image iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13

Since iOS 13, this code return a black image. Any idea?

I also get these warnings logged:

```
InfoLog FlyoverNightShader: WARNING: 0:29: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:31: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
```

```
let mapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
    mapSnapshotOptions.mapType = .satelliteFlyover
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapSnapshotOptions.region = region
    let snapShotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: mapSnapshotOptions)

    snapShotter.start { [weak self]  (snapshot, error)in
        if let image = snapshot?.image {
            main {
                self?.mapImageView.image = image
                self?.mapActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm seeing black `MKMapSnapshotter` images as well, but only in the simulator. When running on a device it works fine for me.

Comment: OMG I thought I was going crazy on this. Since updated to iOS 13, many of my `MKMapSnapshotter` implementations would show with a black image on the simulator. Thanks!! Such an annoying bug...

Comment: Wow, I thought I was going crazy too. Must've spent an hour going over my code.

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, there's an open radar about this MapKit bug:
http://www.openradar.me/33233699